# Can't add Writings to my CV?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks, cv

I'm trying to add a few blog posts to my CV. I keep getting this error though:

> Sorry, we could not retrieve that URL for some reason.

The URL I'm trying to use is just a simple page from my blog: An example: http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/4fa2e7904aa5d81fc295eea7

Is this temporarily broken or what?

Comment: We do a HEAD request first when checking URL’s, and in this case the server is returning a 500 Internal Server Error. If it’s not a server you control, we’ll take a look at being more forgiving on this side.

Comment: @MattSherman heh. It's my blog on a VPS. I've never worried about HEAD requests before. I guess I'll try to fix that. Also, is this a new "feature"? I added some blog posts some time ago and they worked fine and relatively little has changed with my setup

Comment: We added it probably a couple of months ago, part of a change that allows profiles to link to non-HTML content. Doing the HEAD allows us to get the content-type, which in turn allows us to decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing your server’s HEAD response would be helpful in this case (see comments above). But this prompted a discussion by the team here and we decided that the HEAD “preflight” is probably causing as many problems as it solves. So we’ll just do GETs from now on, and see how that goes.

Comment: Well, I actually ended up fixing my server's HEAD response now. Out of curiosity, when a server sent back a "405 method not supported" did it fall back to GET or just fail? I couldn't see too many problems in if it fell back to GET

Comment: Before today’s change, anything not a 200 for a HEAD would fail.

Comment: Yay, I can submit app engine URLs again \o/