# Can't add articles from blog to Careers CV

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

After reviewing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139304/cant-add-writings-to-my-cv), and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125403/cant-add-an-article-on-my-careers-profile), and [this one over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132026/careers-2-0-cannot-retrieve-url-of-blog-post-i-wrote), I feel like I have a slightly different issue causing the same result.

Basically, when I navigate to my [Careers 2.0 profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/mullist) and scroll to the "writings" section, I enter the URL to my WordPress blog into the text input, click the "Get Article" button, and get the "could not retrieve URL" error message.

To verify that this wasn't an issue with HEAD redirecting or returning an error, and that it wasn't an issue with cookies, I ran the following curl command from a terminal:

```
$ curl -I http://www.mullist.com/2014/12/31/literally-the-first-angularjs-app-everyone-writes/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The server is a VPS, so I imagine there's some issue on that end. I was just wondering if anyone had more ideas on how to make my blog visible to Careers 2.0.

Comment: I must be missing something. I didn't expect to be down-voted so quickly. Is there a better answer than the ones I linked?

Comment: I believe you've found your way to Meta. You may wish to read [What is "meta"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) (This should explain the downvotes.)

Comment: @Emrakul, I have read that page, yes. Judging by upvotes on the related posts linked in this question, I felt that my question was appropriate here. Do you disagree?

Comment: Ah, now that I reread the question, I would probably say it's not clear what you're asking. I do understand now generally what your problem is, but would it be possible for you to edit this question to make it clear that you're talking about embedding blog links in Careers 2.0? As it is, this looks like a Wordpress help question, which wouldn't be on-topic here.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I totally missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a reasonable timeout for retrieving articles; it's currently 5 seconds and your blog timed out before we could get the article back. I've increased the timeout to 10 seconds but you might want to check what's taking so long!